# Pointer to derived portion of a class hierarchy

Tags: c++, oop, pointers

This question isn't about a base pointer referencing a derived class in the standard way.  Instead, I have need in my code to support two different IOCTL structures ([SCSI_PASS_THROUGH_DIRECT_EX](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/jj553713%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [SCSI_PASS_THROUGH_DIRECT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff565346%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for reference).  These structures are made part of an encapsulation structure (separate structures for each).  I've sub-classed these encapsulation structures to a common base.

For anyone who hasn't worked with IOCTLs, the processing of the IOCTL requires a pointer to the structure.  In this case, it is the *encasement* structure that is expected.

My question isn't about whether or not base pointers can point to derived classes (I know they can).  What I want to know is, how can I **reliably** point to the start of the derived class in the memory area which **is** this class hierarchy?  The below code illustrates my strategy and compiles in both VS 2010 and Cygwin (GCC 4.5.3).  GCC gives some complaints about the offsetof() macro being used inappropriately (and from all I'm reading, that seems to be *possibly* true), but the code seems to reflect what I'm after in runtime.

Is there a better way of doing this?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <cstddef>

enum IoctlType {
    T1,
    T2
};

struct ptd1 {
    uint32_t Version;
    uint32_t Size;
    uint32_t OffsetOfStuff;
    uint8_t ary[1];
};

struct ptd2 {
    uint32_t Version;
    uint32_t Size;
    uint32_t OffsetOfStuff;
    uint8_t ary[16];
};

struct base {
    IoctlType it;
    virtual void* GetPtr()=0;
};

struct derv1 : base {
    ptd1 passThrough;
    uint8_t ary[15]; // with ptd.ary[1], array is 16 elements
    uint32_t fluff; // realign to DWORD boundary
    uint32_t stuff;

    derv1() {
        it = T1;
        passThrough.Version = 33;
        passThrough.Size = sizeof(ptd1);
        passThrough.OffsetOfStuff = offsetof(derv1, stuff);
    }

    // as the first member of the derv1 struct, this pointer should be the "start"
    virtual void* GetPtr() { return &passThrough; }
};

struct derv2 : base {
    ptd2 passThrough;
    uint32_t stuff;

    derv2() {
        it = T2;
        passThrough.Version = 22;
        passThrough.Size = sizeof(ptd2);
        passThrough.OffsetOfStuff = offsetof(derv2, stuff);
    }

    // as the first member of the derv2 struct, this pointer should be the "start"
    virtual void* GetPtr() { return &passThrough; }
};

int main() {
    base* pBase = new derv1();

    std::cout << "Now, check the results" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "size of base " << sizeof(base) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "size of derv " << sizeof(derv1) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "addr of struct " << pBase << std::endl;
    std::cout << "addr of passThrough " << pBase->GetPtr() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "offset of passThrough " << offsetof(derv1, passThrough)
        << std::endl;

    base* pBase2 = new derv2();

    std::cout << "Now, check the results" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "size of base " << sizeof(base) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "size of derv " << sizeof(derv2) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "addr of struct " << pBase2 << std::endl;
    std::cout << "addr of passThrough " << pBase2->GetPtr() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "offset of passThrough " << offsetof(derv2, passThrough)
        << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think better way is not doing this.

Comment: Can you elaborate what you mean by "*encasement*"?

Comment: @JohnDibling The *encasement* is as depicted in the code.  `struct ptd1` would correspond to the SCSI_PASS_THROUGH_DIRECT structure referenced as the MSDN articles in the post.  Then, `struct derv1` "encases" the structure that Microsoft says I should use.  Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @Slava I'm open to suggestions.  Here's the constraints.  The SCSI_PASS_THROUGH_DIRECT_EX structure isn't available on Windows 7 and older: only Windows 8 and beyond.  My code, however, will be running on both Windows versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much internal debate, I resolved that Slava's comment is the most helpful; don't do it.  To that end, I've essentially made a wrapper structure which knows which structure to use.  The criteria are:

- Is this Windows 7 and earlier, or Windows 8 and later
- If Windows 8 and later, is this a 32-bit proc on a 64-bit OS

Then, there are *appropriate* functions for getting/setting the values desired.  The final product looks something like this:

```
struct ScsiPassThruExWBuffers {
    SCSI_PASS_THROUGH_DIRECT_EX  passThru;
    unsigned char cdbExt[259]; // 260 by SCSI Standard
    int fluff;  // realign
    unsigned char senseInfo[256];
    STOR_ADDR_BTL8 addrInfo;
};

struct ScsiPassThru32ExWBuffers {
    SCSI_PASS_THROUGH_DIRECT32_EX  passThru;
    unsigned char cdbExt[259]; // 260 by SCSI Standard
    int fluff;  // realign
    unsigned char senseInfo[256];
    STOR_ADDR_BTL8 addrInfo;
};

struct ScsiPassThruWBuffers {
    SCSI_PASS_THROUGH_DIRECT  passThru;
    unsigned char senseInfo[256];
};

enum PassThruType {
    PassThru,
    PassThruEx,
    PassThru32Ex
};

struct Wrapper {
    void * pStruct;
    PassThruType ptt;
    unsigned int ioctlCode;
    unsigned int aggregateStructSize;

    // ctors/dtors
    Wrapper();
    Wrapper(Wrapper const& source); // copy c-tor
    ~Wrapper(); // delete memory allocated for pStruct;

    // several setters/getters for the properties in the structures

    private:
    Wrapper& operator=(Wrapper const& rhs); // no implementation
};
```

This leaves all of the aggregate, or encapsulation, structures of the Pass Through Structures as PODs and the ability to reliably determine the offsets is sound.